Finding the Cramer Rao bound

Let $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ be a sample of i.i.d random variables with pdf $$f(x;\theta)=(1-\theta)\chi_{[-1/2,0]}+(1+\theta)\chi_{[0,1/2]}$$ where $\theta\in(-1,1)$. Find the Cramer Rao bound.

So to do so I need to compute the Fisher information. $$L(x;\theta)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}f(x_i;\theta)=(1-\theta)^{n_1}(1+\theta)^{n_2}$$ where $n_1$ is the amount of times we obtained a value within the interval $[-1/2,0]$ while $n_2$ is the amount of times we obtained a value within the interval $(0,1/2]$, so that $n_1+n_2=n$. Now, $$l(x;\theta)=\log L(x;\theta)=n_1\log(1-\theta)+n_2\log(1+\theta)$$ $$S(x;\theta)=\frac{\partial l}{\partial\theta}=-\frac{n_1}{1-\theta}+\frac{n_2}{1+\theta}$$ $$J(x;\theta)=-\frac{\partial^2 l}{\partial\theta^2}=\frac{n_1}{(1-\theta)^2}+\frac{n_2}{(1+\theta)^2}$$ $$I(\theta)=\mathbb{E}(J(x;\theta))=\frac{1}{(1-\theta)^2}\mathbb{E}(n_1)+\frac{1}{(1+\theta)^2}\mathbb{E}(n_2)$$ where $J(x;\theta)$ is the derivative of the score function and $I(\theta)$ is the Fisher information. The problem comes (supposing that everything up to this point is correct) when I have to calculate the expecte value of $n_i$, i.e. $\mathbb{E}(n_i)$ which I don't know how to do so. I mean, I guess this should be $$\mathbb{E}(n_i)=\frac{1}{2}$$ but I have nothing to support such hypothesis. Can anyone help me find the Cramer Rao bound?

You asked how the $n_i$'s depend on the sample here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4932857/321264. How come the responses there don't help?

@StubbornAtom Could you please confirm that my result is good? $$\mathbb{E}(n_1)=\mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}1_{[-\frac{1}{2},0]}(x_i)\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}\left(1_{[-\frac{1}{2},0]}(x_i)\right)$$ So we get, $$\mathbb{E}\left(1_{[-\frac{1}{2},0]}(x_i)\right)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}2x1_{[-\frac{1}{2},0]}(x_i)dx=-\frac{1}{4}$$ Finally, $$\mathbb{E}(n_1)=-\frac{n}{4}$$ Similarly, $$\mathbb{E}(n_2)=\frac{n}{4}$$

$1_A$ is supposed to be the indicator variable corresponding to the set $A$; you used this notation in the pdf of the linked post. What is then $E(1_A(X))$?

Soo, $E(1_A(X))=\int_{X}1_A(x)dP=\int_{A}dP=P(A)$ but I don't know how to calculate this last probability in my case.

I mean, $P(A)=P([-\frac{1}{2},0])=1$ if $x\in A$ and $0$ otherwise?
